# Issue install cordova camera plugin with cordova 4.x

Tags: cordova, cordova-plugins, cordova-3

I am maintaining a legacy hybrid mobile application using cordova 4.3.0. I have problem installing the cordova camera plugin. I follow [install doc](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-camera#installation) but it was failed with these errors:

```js
cordova plugin add org.apache.cordova.camera

Fetching plugin "org.apache.cordova.camera" via plugin registry
npm http GET http://registry.cordova.io/org.apache.cordova.camera
npm http GET http://registry.cordova.io/org.apache.cordova.camera
npm http GET http://registry.cordova.io/org.apache.cordova.camera
Error: connect ETIMEDOUT 50.17.177.14:80
    at Object.exports._errnoException (util.js:849:11)
    at exports._exceptionWithHostPort (util.js:872:20)
    at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (net.js:1060:14)
```

I guess this http://registry.cordova.io/org.apache.cordova.camera no longer exists.

I notice this statement:

> Older versions of cordova can still install via the deprecated id

I don't really understand what does this mean.

Is there anyone having experience with this issue and know how to solve it.

Comment: try adding it locally after downloading repo. Alternative plugin can be found here : https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-camera

Comment: @HardikVaghani this is what being referred to in the question. do you mean  downloading it from the master branch? or which versions?

Comment: @channaly try with this command - cordova plugin add https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-camera.git

Comment: `cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-camera` this will work too.

Comment: @channaly But i m not sure whether it works with cordova cli 4x Better upgrade your CLI which is very beneficial

Comment: @HardikVaghani I tried that It did not work.

Comment: @Gandhi I understood that but I am not allowed to upgrade it yet.

Comment: @channaly Sorry i dont have CLI 4x to investigate further.